# Did I copy that wrong?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, progressive-matrix

```
OEEE
XOOX
EXEX
XEOE
```

Exactly one letter needs to be exchanged into one of the other two. But where and which one?

I intended this to be part of [Monthly Topic Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/monthly-topic-challenge-2-iq-puzzle-parody). This is sort of a hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's

> The 2nd E in the 3rd row, it needs to be an O

How come:

> The whole grid looks like [Tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) on a 4x4 grid. Given there are 5 Xs and 4 Os, it should be O's turn to play. Playing in the 2nd empty (E) square in the 3rd row guarantees a win for the player with the Os, completing both a vertical 3 in a row and a diagonal one.
>  $$ \begin{array}{cccc}  \mathsf{\text{O}}  &  &  & \\\mathsf{\text{X}}& \mathsf{\text{O}} & \mathsf{\text{O}} & \mathsf{\text{X}} \\ & \mathsf{\text{X}} & \color{lime}{\mathsf{\text{O}}}  & \mathsf{\text{X}} \\ \mathsf{\text{X}}&  & \mathsf{\text{O}} &  \end{array}$$

Comment: Another good one. This must be it.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is the intention, but

> X is present in rows `2,3,4` and columns `1,2,4`
>  O is present in rows `1,2,4` and columns `1,2,3`
>  E is present in rows `1,3,4` and columns `1,2,3,4`

So

> If the constraint is `present in 3 rows/columns`, the only way is to change the E in column 1 (all other columns have 2 Es). Can only be changed to `X` to not break constraint for O.

Comment: @Jlee After seeing your answer, I'm fairly sure mine is a happy coincidence - TicTacToe reference makes a lot of sense, with `E` perhaps representing "empty"

Comment: but yours is simpler, so I was actually thinking that it is probably correct.

Comment: This would be a good answer for an IQ test kind of question but it is missing the parody aspect, so it is not what I had in mind.

Comment: I think the progressive matrix tag made us think it was an IQ-style question, since we are used to seeing that tag on those questions, and that directed our focus away from the tic-tac-toe aspect. However, the tag is probably good, but my being misled was due to my incorrect narrow interpretation of the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> the 2nd E in the 4th row needs to be an O.

Reasoning:

> Tic-tac-toe comes to mind. There are 5 X's, but just 4 O's, so it seems we need to change one of the E's to an O, but which one?
>
>  The X's form 3 rows of 2, where 2 of those rows are connected at one point. Therefore we must place the O so that that setup holds true for O's also. That means the O must replace one of the E's on the bottom row.
>  To decide which one, we notice the number of columns and rows taken up by X is 3, so in order to match that, the O must replace the E in the 2nd column.

Comment: Your reasoning starts out exactly as what I had in mind but you got to a different answer and the reasons for it to me look more complicated that what I was thinking.